# Can I have three main characters, each with their own love interest, in the same book?

Tags: characters, pov

I am plotting a book which has three main characters. And I want each one of these characters to have a love interest so the focus won't be on just one of them. So can I do that or is it too much and a bit cheesy?

Also do you guys think that it's better to write this novel in a series or a stand-alone with three POVs, and by series I mean three companion novels for each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing in first person ensemble, and it sounds like you might be, then not only does it work to have each of your three main characters have their own love interest it makes the story better. *As long as* you don't repeat yourself that is. Ensemble narratives work best when the reader understands the POV characters through whose eyes they are seeing the story unfold and identifies with them as unique individuals (See S.M. Stirling's [Nantucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantucket_series) and [Emberverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emberverse_series) books for a good example of the first person ensemble style), this only works when your POV characters are actually unique individuals.

If you are telling one story write one book if you are telling three stories write three books. If your three main/POV characters are all participating in one adventure then tell different parts of that story through each of them all together at the same time, if the events they experience are separated in time and/or space then by all means render them as separate stories.

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually helped a lot!